# how to access embedded foreach value use outside the loop in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to display embedded inside the foreach loop value can display outside the loops,
but I got only one value, anyone one solve my issue

```
public function profit_loss_account1()
{
        $deposit_amount = 0;
        $discount = 0;
        $deposit_fine = 0;
        $deposit_date='';

    $deposite=$this->studentfeemaster_model->fetch_fees_deposite();

    foreach ($deposite as $deposite_value) {

        $amount_detail=json_decode($deposite_value->amount_detail);

        foreach ($amount_detail as $amount_detail_key=>$amount_detail_value) {
           $deposit_amount= $amount_detail_value->amount;
             $deposit_date=$amount_detail_value->date;
             $deposit_fine = $amount_detail_value->amount_fine."<br>";
             $deposit_amount .' - '.$deposit_date."<br>"; // i needed data dispaly correct here but i need outside the loops
        }
    }

 echo $deposit_amount; // got one value here 

}
```

display here i got correct output

```
$deposit_amount .' - '.$deposit_date."<br>"; // i needed data dispaly correct here but i need outside the loops
```

i expected output like this but outside the loops how to do

output:

```
1000 - 2020-02-05
12000 - 2020-02-07
0 - 2020-02-07
0 - 2020-02-07
12600 - 2019-06-29
8000 - 2019-03-12
3200 - 2019-07-26
200.00 - 2020-02-06
4000 - 2019-05-24
6000 - 2019-12-02
```

outside the loops

```
 echo $deposit_amount; // got one value here
```

i got output like this

output :

```
1000 - 2020-02-05
```

Comment: Posting expected output may helpful. You can do `echo $amount_detail_value->amount;` inside the loop, so all the values will be printed.

Answer (score 2):

define your `$deposit_amount` as empty string before the foreach loop if you want concenate it with string, dont forget to add `=`

for example

```php
$deposit_amount = '';
foreach($deposit as $value) {
   $deposit_amount .= ' - '.$value->date. '<br>';
}
echo $deposit_amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Init your var before the loop. The loop update var. So you can use it outside the loop.

example :

```
$var = 0;

foreach ($values as $value) {
   $var ++;
}

echo $var;
```